# Passing results from PHP class to AJAX and back to the calling script

Tags: php, ajax

I have a class which returns a set of data from the database. The class is called by ajax and the results need to be returned back to the `index.php` so that I can format and display the results in a table format.

Problem: I'm unable to return the results throug ajax and back to a php variable.
Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

```
<php
class Questions 
{  public function displayQuestions()
   {   
     return $this->questionArray;   
   } // contains set of data from db
}
?>
```

Return the dataset from the class and pass it to the `$var` so that I can format the data for display

`index.php`:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="questiondev" ><?php $var[] = returned by ajax ?> </div> 



<div id="questionButton">
   <form method="POST" name="form_questions" action="">
      <TEXTAREA NAME="saveqa"  id="saveqa"></TEXTAREA>
       <BUTTON class="btn_save" id ="btn_save" NAME="btn_save">Ask</BUTTON>
   </form>
</div>  
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script>           
          $(document).ready(function() { 
          $('#btn_save').on('click', function() { 
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false, 
            url: "testData.php",
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(info){
            $('#questiondev').html(info[0]);
            console.log(" reponse :"+ info);
            }
         });
        }); 

        $('#btn_save').trigger("click");
         });                  
        </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: u didn't put the data setting to the ajax

Comment: You cannot put an ajax return back into a PHP variable. PHP is server side and since your page is already rendered, you cannot update any of its server-side code. Line 3 of your markup will never work. All you can do with AJAX is update a javascript variable, and the pass that into your HTML/DOM.

Comment: Why not just do the formatting in your php file, echo it back, then use the ajax callback function to update your div? It would be much easier to manipulate that array via php before sending the response back.

Answer (score 0):

**add**

`data:$("form").serialize(),` U need to serialize the form

```
<div id="questionButton">
   <form method="POST" name="form_questions" action="">
      <TEXTAREA NAME="saveqa"  id="saveqa"></TEXTAREA>
       <BUTTON class="btn_save" id ="btn_save" NAME="btn_save">Ask</BUTTON>
   </form>
</div>  
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script>           
          $(document).ready(function() { 
          $('#btn_save').on('click', function() { 
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false, 
            url: "testData.php",
            data:$("form").serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(info){
            $('#questiondev').html(info[0]);
            console.log(" reponse :"+ info);
            }
         });
        }); 

        $('#btn_save').trigger("click");
         });                  
        </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hello thank you for your help but Im still having problems. the script seem to be in a loop for some reason. the testData.php works by itself but at the sametime the data isn't coming over eithe.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're echoing your results in json format.  It appears that if your query is successful, $questionArray  gets set, but is not echoed.  Plus you can't just echo $questionArray  - it must be output in json format for the Ajax code to accept it.

Try this - after $questionArray is set:

```
 $encodedJSON = json_encode($questionArray);
 echo $encodedJSON;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't insert result of AJAX request into PHP variable like this. When you run php page web server willl render it, and then javascript is run by browser, which means, that you can't edit PHP variables from javascript, because PHP runs on server and JS runs on client.

Why do you want to do this? Maybe it is flaw in app design, give more information and maybe we can help you more so you won't need to do this. If you want to format data, then format them before you send them back to AJAX :)